# Oracle math functions

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding

I am trying to get a rounded value in Oracle (using SQL Developer) through following statement:

```
ROUND((1-POWER((SUM(D.PFY/100*E.OUT_8_)/SUM(E,OUT_8_)), (1/(SUM(PHOTO*E.OUT_8_)/SUM(E.OUT_8_)))))*1000000, 0) AS PFYPPM
```

However, I am getting an error as:

> invalid number of arguments.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Oracle error messages are actually helpful.

*invalid number of arguments*

Check your function calls.

sum() takes only one argument.

```
SUM(E,OUT_8_)
```

should probably be

```
SUM(E.OUT_8_)
```